# How to change language for input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to type from a normal keyboard but the language will be different. In my case I am using the Dhivehi language. What is the idea behind this?

I could not find any help on Google for this. The solution should be cross-platform and cross-browser compatible.

Comment: You want to user to be able to select the language for a specific input?

Comment: Is something like [this](http://www.jawish.org/blog/archives/348-Javascript-Thaana-Keyboard-version-4.2.1.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Worthwelle thanks. I didn’t notice that before. It’s clean and easier to use than making one on my own.

Answer (score 1):

To tell the browser that an [`input` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) contains text in a different language, you can try adding the [`lang` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang), which is [supported by every HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). Here is an example with a text field that accepts French:

```html
<label>
  Comment allez-vous ?
  <input lang="fr-fr">
</label>
```

Ideally, for an `input` with a different `lang`, browsers should use the spell-check dictionary of the specified language, and on mobile, they should present the keyboard for that language. I haven’t tested if current browsers actually act that way.

Comment: Already got my answer from the comment for the question. But this was extremely helpful as well. Currently I do not think thaana is supported by many/any browser. Thanks for the tip and help.